# Firebase Functions error when calling Stripe

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm an iOS developer with very little experience in both Javascript and server code so I'm a little lost here.

I'm getting an error when I create a new user in firebase and trigger a function to create a new user in stripe. Here is my firebase function straight from Stripe's docs.

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => { 
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
    return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customerId});
  });
```

I successfully create a new user in Stripe with a customer ID.
[image]
I get is this error in my firebase logs and don't capture the customer ID so I can save it in firestore. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to interpret this message. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
createStripeCustomer
ReferenceError: customerId is not defined at exports.createStripeCustomer.functions.auth.user.onCreate (/srv/index.js:120:93) at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

I have also tried this return changing customerId to ID

```
return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: ID});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, from the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create), that the response object contains an id property.  Perhaps you meant to write this line instead:

```
return admin.firestore()
    .collection('stripe_customers')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set({customer_id: customer.id});  // use the ID property here
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - still getting this error                              ```createStripeCustomer
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at exports.createStripeCustomer.functions.auth.user.onCreate (/srv/index.js:123:33) at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)```

Comment: So you're saying that stripe returned an undefined value from its API?

Comment: it seems like stripe is not returning a customer ID even though I see one created in the Stripe dashboard

Comment: Are you able to log `customer.id` after creating the customer in Stripe? If you're using `await` there is no reason the `customer` would be undefined afterward. Can you share the revised snippet when using `customer.id`?

Comment: Additionally, is there a reason why you're `return`ing the firebase `set()` line? My reading of the Firebase auth event docs [0] doesn't indicate that there any expectation of a return value, so try removing that.

[0] https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation

Comment: I thought the same thing about await. how can the customer id be missing if we are waiting for the response? I don't understand that part. I removed the return. Here is the error snippit     ```createStripeCustomer
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at exports.createStripeCustomer.functions.auth.user.onCreate (/srv/index.js:123:33) at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)```.

Comment: ```exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => { 
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email}); 
    admin.firestore()
    .collection('stripe_customers')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set({customer_id: customer.id});  // use the ID property here
  });```

Comment: I am unable to log customer.id

Comment: If you're seeing the customers created successfully in your Dashboard, this is unlikely to be a Stripe issue, but rather in how the firebase function works. Are you able to access logs of the function executions at all to inspect the object returned for `customer`? If the client encountered an error, I'd expect an except to be raised before the one you describe. Can you show how `stripe` is initialized before this `export` definition? (Make sure to obscure you keys)

Comment: The `return` statement needs to be in place in order to prevent Cloud Functions from terminating too early.  Either that, or await the call to Firestore.  In any event, the function callback must return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.

Comment: This is how I initialize Stripe / cloud functions

Comment: `const functions = require('firebase-functions');`
`const admin = require('firebase-admin');`
const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';
admin.initializeApp();

Comment: I am not able to access logs of the function executions at all to inspect the object returned for customer? I'd like to learn how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I finally ended up. I used a promise instead of await.

```js
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => { 
  const stripePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stripe.customers.create({
      email: user.email
    }, (err, customer) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(customer);
          stripePromise
            .then(customer => {
              return admin.firestore()
                .collection('stripe_customers')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .set({customer_id: customer.id});
            })
            .catch(error => { 
              console.log(`error resolving promise ${error}`)
            })
      }
    });
  })
});
```